# SQL Server While Loop Not Returning expected Value

Tags: sql-server, function

Here the code from my function:

```
-- Get Country Names
DECLARE getCountriesName CURSOR FOR
    SELECT c.Name
    FROM VocabCountry c
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN ProjectCountryRelations cr
            ON cr.CountryId = c.Id
    WHERE 
        c.Id = @project_id;

-- Finally Create list to return 
OPEN getCountriesName;
FETCH NEXT FROM getCountriesName INTO @Name;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN  

    SET @listOfItems = @listOfItems + @Name + ', '
    FETCH NEXT FROM getCountriesName INTO @Name;

END;
CLOSE getCountriesName;
DEALLOCATE getCountriesName;
```

I am expecting a list of comma separated values, for example, like so:

```
Canada, United States of America,
```

I verified that the `SELECT` returns the countries expected.

Thanks for any help!

Eric

Comment: What output does the above code produce? I think you forgot the '@' in front of your cursor.

Comment: Do you initialize `@listOfItems` to anything before the loop?

Comment: "I am expecting ..." - okay, fine. But with us not having your tables and data, it's worth telling us what you're currently *getting*. I'm guessing `NULL` (as would @MikaelEriksson, I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on SQL Server **2008** or newer, you could easily do this with a single SELECT and some `FOR XML PATH` magic :-)

```
SELECT 
    STUFF(
       (SELECT ',' + c.Name
        FROM VocabCountry c
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN ProjectCountryRelations cr
        ON cr.CountryId = c.Id
        FOR XML PATH('')
       ), 1, 1, '')
```

That should return a comma-separated list of those country names for you. No ugly and awful cursor needed!

Answer (score 2):

Using the `FOR XML PATH` will concat the values with commas.

Using the `STUFF` Function will remove the first comma you don't want.

So use this:

```
SELECT 
    STUFF(
       (SELECT ',' + c.Name
        FROM VocabCountry c
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN ProjectCountryRelations cr
        ON cr.CountryId = c.Id
        WHERE cr.Id = @project_id
        FOR XML PATH('')
       ), 1, 1, '');
```

See this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd648/21